# Installing datashader LLVM_CONFIG

Tags: llvm, datashader

I have attempted installing datashader on my linux system python3. I have tried:

```
pip install datashader 
pip3 install datashader
```

These both fail due to `LLVM_CONFIG` not being in path.

So, I tried to install LLVM and I have something but not the correct result in /opt/rh that are both devtoolset-7 and llvm-toolset-7. I have also installed clang. The error still exists with the datashader install.

What is the most efficient way to install datashader and all other nesc. dependencies?

Comment: What's your Linux distribution? Does it use LLVM as its compiler not GCC?

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way to install datashader is to use conda, which will automatically handle all the libraries datashader depends on.  However, it should be possible to install using pip, with more work, so please file a bug report at https://github.com/pyviz/datashader/issues listing your system details and the commands you executed to install datashader and its dependencies.